# Python dictionary key pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is formatted this way:

```
    enemyType = {"skeleton": [{"HP": random.randint(12,15), "DMG": random.randint(3,7)}],
        "zombie": [{"HP": random.randint(21,33), "DMG": random.randint(5,9)}],
        "golem": [{"HP": random.randint(40,55), "DMG": random.randint(6,13)}]}


    for key, value in enemyType.items():
     print(key, value)
     for k, v in value:
       print(k)
```

Output is:

```
    skeleton [{'HP': 14, 'DMG': 3}]
    HP
    zombie [{'HP': 28, 'DMG': 8}]
    HP
    golem [{'HP': 45, 'DMG': 8}]
    HP
```

How do I get the values for 'HP' and 'DMG'?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you format this way though?

Comment: This code does not produce *any* output; it produces a `NameError`.

Comment: @JonSG That won't work. The value associated with the key "skeleton" is, for reasons I cannot discern, a list

Comment: @Codist Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to correct the typo in your for loop.

```
import random

enemyType = {
    'skeleton': [{'HP': random.randint(12, 15), 'DMG': random.randint(3, 7)}],
    'zombie': [{'HP': random.randint(21, 33), 'DMG': random.randint(5, 9)}],
    'golem': [{'HP': random.randint(40, 55), 'DMG': random.randint(6, 13)}],
}

[(k,v[0]['HP'],v[0]['DMG']) for k, v in enemyType.items()]

#output
[('skeleton', 15, 3), ('zombie', 28, 6), ('golem', 41, 7)]
```

---

If you just want `'HP'` and `'DMG'` then:

```
[(v[0]['HP'],v[0]['DMG']) for k, v in enemyType.items()]

#output
[(15, 3), (28, 6), (41, 7)]
```

---

If you want to remove list from your dictionary just do:

```
enemyType = {k:v[0] for k,v in enemyType.items()}

#output
{'skeleton': {'HP': 15, 'DMG': 3},
 'zombie': {'HP': 28, 'DMG': 6},
 'golem': {'HP': 41, 'DMG': 7}}
```

---

```
for key, value in enemyType.items():
    for k,v in value.items():
        print(k,v)

HP 15
DMG 3
HP 28
DMG 6
HP 41
DMG 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Values of the dictionary -> a list containing one item -> keys & values:

```py
import random

enemyType = {
    'skeleton': [{'HP': random.randint(12, 15), 'DMG': random.randint(3, 7)}],
    'zombie': [{'HP': random.randint(21, 33), 'DMG': random.randint(5, 9)}],
    'golem': [{'HP': random.randint(40, 55), 'DMG': random.randint(6, 13)}],
}

for k, v in enemyType.items():
    d = v[0]
    print(k, d['HP'], d['DMG'])
```

output:

```
skeleton 14 3
zombie 21 9
golem 40 11
```

I guess you can eliminate the list so that your structure be like:

```py
enemyType = {
    'skeleton': {'HP': random.randint(12, 15), 'DMG': random.randint(3, 7)},
    'zombie': {'HP': random.randint(21, 33), 'DMG': random.randint(5, 9)},
    'golem': {'HP': random.randint(40, 55), 'DMG': random.randint(6, 13)},
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the values for `HP` and `DMG` by iterating over the dictionary and then accessing the keys of the nested dictionary inside the list. Something like:

```py
for k, v in enemyType.items():
    print(k, v)
    for enemy in v:
        hp = enemy['HP']
        dmg = enemy['DMG']
        print("HP:", hp, "DMG:", dmg)
```

Output:

```
skeleton [{'HP': 12, 'DMG': 3}]
HP: 12 DMG: 3
zombie [{'HP': 33, 'DMG': 7}]
HP: 33 DMG: 7
golem [{'HP': 45, 'DMG': 6}]
HP: 45 DMG: 6
```

*[CODE DEMO](https://onecompiler.com/python/3zsq9hb9n)*

Answer (score 1):

> *"... How do I get the values for 'HP' and 'DMG'? ..."*

The values are within a *[list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range)*, so you'll need to specify this indice first.

```py
import random as r
d = {'skeleton': [{'HP': r.randint(12,15), 'DMG': r.randint(3,7)}],
     'zombie':   [{'HP': r.randint(21,33), 'DMG': r.randint(5,9)}],
     'golem':    [{'HP': r.randint(40,55), 'DMG': r.randint(6,13)}]}
for k, v in d.items():
    hp, dmg = v[0]['HP'], v[0]['DMG']
    print(k, hp, dmg)
```

Optionally, use only a *[dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)*.

```py
import random as r
d = {'skeleton': {'HP': r.randint(12,15), 'DMG': r.randint(3,7)},
     'zombie':   {'HP': r.randint(21,33), 'DMG': r.randint(5,9)},
     'golem':    {'HP': r.randint(40,55), 'DMG': r.randint(6,13)}}
for k, v in d.items():
    hp, dmg = v['HP'], v['DMG']
    print(k, hp, dmg)
```

Output

```
skeleton 14 4
zombie 28 8
golem 54 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happened in your existing code: basically you accidentally formatted your data structure and your `for` loops in a way that didn't cause an explicit error which is usually how you know something is wrong.

```py
for key, value in enemyDict.items():
    print(key, value) #here value is a list containing a single dict
    
    for k, v in value: #Iterating over the list yields a single iteration over this loop
        #For each loop iteration you are trying to unpack the new value into two new variables.
        #  This only works here because your dict (the first and only value in the list)
        #  also only has two keys. Treating the dict as an iterable (without calling .items
        #  or .values for example) will simply iterate over the keys
       print(k) #here k will be the first key in the dict: "HP", and v will be the second: "DMG".
```

If you did not mean to have the extra list it is quite simple to remove it:

```py
enemyType = {
    "skeleton": {"HP": random.randint(12,15), "DMG": random.randint(3,7)},
    "zombie": {"HP": random.randint(21,33), "DMG": random.randint(5,9)},
    "golem": {"HP": random.randint(40,55), "DMG": random.randint(6,13)}
}

for key, value in enemyDict.items():
    print(key, value)
    for k, v in value.items(): #note the added "items" to get key and value pairs from the dict
        print(k, v)
```

If you did mean for the list to be there (for example if you are trying to represent multiple instances of each enemy), you can also adjust the loop accordingly:

```py
enemyType = {
    #using list comprehensions to create multiple enemies of each type
    "skeleton": [{"HP": random.randint(12,15), "DMG": random.randint(3,7)} for _ in range(3)],
    "zombie": [{"HP": random.randint(21,33), "DMG": random.randint(5,9)} for _ in range(4)],
    "golem": [{"HP": random.randint(40,55), "DMG": random.randint(6,13)} for _ in range(2)]
}

for enemy_type, instances in enemyDict.items(): #get enemy type and list of enemy instances of that type
    print(enemy_type)
    for enemy_instance in instances: #each instance is a dict containing specific "HP" and "DMG" for each enemy
        print(enemy_instance["HP"], enemy_instance["DMG"])
```